# How do I render math (or a PNG) inside of a TikZ text arc?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, amsmath, amssymb

I'm trying to get a "hex dot" symbol to be in a text arc in `tikz`, but I'm not succeeding.

Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\hexdot}{$\therefore\atop\because$}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (myfirstpic) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{round_test_image.png}};
    \node (One) at (-5,0) {};
    \node (Two) at (5,0) {};
    \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{-2.5ex}}
    \draw [-,thick,black!0,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift|B\hexdot{} O\hexdot{} T\hexdot{} T\hexdot{} O\hexdot{} M\hexdot{} T\hexdot{} E\hexdot{} X\hexdot{} T\hexdot{}}}}] (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);
    \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
    \draw [-,thick,black!0,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift|T\hexdot{} O\hexdot{} P\hexdot{}  T\hexdot{} E\hexdot{} X\hexdot{} T\hexdot{}}}}] (One) to [bend left=45] (Two);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I can add `\hexdot` or `\hexdot{}` to a node label, or elsewhere in the document, and have it appear correctly. However, if I put it in either the bottom text arc or the upper text arc, the document just hangs forever while trying to render. If I write the arcs without any `\hexdot{}` symbols, it works just fine.

I have also tried this using a .png version of the hexdot character, but that doesn't work either, as the rendering also hangs indefinitely.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you kindly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. As a new member, it is recommended to visit these pages https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx and https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour and also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ to know about Minimal Example.

Otherwise, more specifically to your question: I do not understand how the Hebrew language and font is necessary in your example ! Is it absolutely necessary ? in other words, does it change the behaviour of your code and the sense of your question? if no please consider editing (minimizing) your question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, R.N. The bit about the Hebrew is probably not relevant. I have edited my OP to work towards a more minimized version of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the math content into braces. (Also you may want to use `\genfrac` or something of that sort instead of `\atop`. This answer also work with your macro.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\hexdot}{$\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\therefore}{\because}$}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (myfirstpic) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{example-image-a.png}};
    \node (One) at (-5,0) {};
    \node (Two) at (5,0) {};
    \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{-2.5ex}}
    \draw [-,thick,black!0,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift|B{\hexdot} O{\hexdot} T{\hexdot} T{\hexdot} O{\hexdot} M{\hexdot} T{\hexdot} E{\hexdot} X{\hexdot} T{\hexdot}}}}] (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);
    \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
    \draw [-,thick,black!0,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift|T{\hexdot} O{\hexdot} P{\hexdot}  T{\hexdot} E{\hexdot} X{\hexdot} T{\hexdot}}}}] (One) to [bend left=45] (Two);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As I do not have your png image I use an image that is included in most TeX installations.

Comment: I believe example-image-duck is also available in most TeX distributions, and it is much better than the boring example-image-a.png

Comment: Marked as solved! Thank you so much! I had no idea that the solution was going to be something as simple as bracketing the statement. I greatly appreciate your help.